# Decide whether a system of polynomial equalities and inequalities is feasible?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, inequalities

Consider a system of polynomial equations $f_1(x) = ... = f_n(x) = 0$ and polynomial inequalities $g_1(x), ... ,g_m(x) \ge 0$. All polynomials are in rational coefficients, $x = (x_1, ... , x_l)$ is short-hand notation for many variables (which are real of course).

I would like to know what is the most efficient, non-numerical, way to decide whether there exist an $x$ such that the system is true.

Currently I am using `CylindricalDecomposition`, and check if it returns `False`, but this feels like an overkill.

--- Edit

`FindInstance` indeed works much faster. I could not tell how it works internally however, is it a numerical or exact approach?

Comment: Possibly `FindInstance` will be faster. You will want to  check the documentation to be sure it is foolproof for the conditions of interest.

Comment: This is empty talk without an example of such system.

Comment: This is a rigorously formulated and well studied problem in real algebraic geometry. The question is merely what is the best - among many - of the algorithms currently implemented in Mathematica

Comment: @giuliobullsaver Hi, in the details section of the documentation of FindInstance, the following is mentioned: "With exact symbolic input, FindInstance gives exact results. " In Options > WorkingPrecision> there is an example that shows that FindInstance can find an approximate solution.

Comment: I believe `FindInstance` gives a guaranteed result for the situation at hand. That is, if it returns `{}` then indeed there are no solutions. I have not checked the documentation on this though.